# changing styleClass on Condition for primefaces components

Tags: primefaces

Is there any way to change styleClass based on condition for primefaces components?

if there is,
please suggest me.

I wrote like this..

```
styleClass="#{(bean.comment==null) ? style1 : style2}"
```

is it correct way to give value for styleClass?

please suggest me better ways if any.

thank u

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this, but it needs little modification. You should return string which represents class name:

```
styleClass="#{(bean.comment==null) ? 'style1' : 'style2'}"
```

Another approach is to calculate this condition in backing bean, and use simpler EL:

```
styleClass="#{bean.style}"
```

and in backing bean:

```
public String getStyle() {
  return (comment == null) ? "style1" : "style2";
}
```